# Log Parser VBScripting Issue

Tags: windows, vbscript, logparser

I have been trying to figure out a solution to the following problem:

- I have been building a VBScript to pull a series of security audit events using
  the windows `LogParser` 2.2 tool.
- The goal of the script is to parse audit logs from already collected and "saved off"
  `evt(x)` files inside of a weekly audit folder structure.  Imagine for a moment
  that you're dealing with an entire network of windows systems that have a WMI service
  already running that collects these logs weekly for review.  As such, the folder
  structure stays consistent from week to week (e.g. `/../audits/date/windows/XXX.evt`).
- The summary file for these weekly audit files is text based, which is not conducive for
  auditing hundreds of machines weekly.
- I have figured the basic syntax so that I can pull events and output them to html with
  any issues. My struggle comes with added the additional functions I need it to have.
- The script needs the following functionality :

  1. at startup, it needs to prompt the user to enter the file path where they want
     to parse audit data from (e.g. `../2013-07-03/windows/*`)
  2. The user's response then needs to bound to a value, and used to replace a
      variable I specify throughout the entire script.  The desired result is that 
      script kicks off the query events in the script at the user identified location.
- I have tried using an inputbox with a regular expression object, and I can't get the script to go through and replace the variable (`filePathReplace`) so that the script will run the query events where I specified.

I don't care if an input box is used or not.  More than anything I just need a way to feed the script a file path, and apply it throughout the script so that logparser kicks off my instructions in that specific folder.

An excerpt of what I have is included below.  Any and all help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you all for your time.

*CODE EXCERPT*   (this is the core components of the script and one of the audit events)

```
Dim oLogQuery
Dim oEVTInputFormat
Dim oTPLOutputFormat 
Dim strQuery

Set oLogQuery = CreateObject("MSUtil.LogQuery")

' Create Input Format object
Set oEVTInputFormat = CreateObject("MSUtil.LogQuery.EventLogInputFormat")
oEVTInputFormat.direction = "BW"

' Create Output Format object
Set oTPLOutputFormat = CreateObject("MSUtil.LogQuery.TemplateOutputFormat")

' Create query text  (the variable substitution should occur where I state
' filePathReplace. To make the script run without this function, subsitiute
' that variable for 'Security'

' Audit log clearing - 517

oTPLOutputFormat.tpl = "C:\Program Files\Log Parser 2.2\EventFilters\EventLogs-TPL-517.tpl"

strQuery = "SELECT TimeGenerated, EventID, " & _
  "EXTRACT_TOKEN (Strings,3,'|') AS clientUserName, " & _
  "EXTRACT_TOKEN (Strings,4,'|') AS hostName, " & _
  "EXTRACT_TOKEN (Message,0,'Primary User Name') AS Message " & _ 
  "INTO 'C:\Program Files\Log Parser 2.2\EventFilters\AuditLogCleared-517.htm' " & _
  "FROM 'filePathReplace' " & _
  "WHERE EventID = 517"

oLogQuery.ExecuteBatch strQuery, oEVTInputFormat, oTPLOutputFormat
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`Shell.BrowseForFolder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774065) method is arguably the best solution for your problem. Example:

```
Set os = CreateObject("shell.application")
basedir = os.Namespace("C:\some\folder").Self.Path
Set fldr = os.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select Folder:", &h10&, basedir)
If Not fldr Is Nothing Then
  'do stuff
End If
```

Use the returned object like this:

```
strQuery = "SELECT ..." & _
  ...
  "FROM '" & fldr.Self.Path & "' " & _
  "WHERE EventID = 517"
```